# Matlab how to get file with path only

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to get file with path only without any ui.

Now i am using

```
[file, path] = uigetfile('*.*');
```

What i want to do is simple get that file without ui.
something like

```
[file] = getfile(path)
```

Is there any way how to get that file but same format too as from uigetfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you know where your file is and/or use [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) and its `out.folder` argument, which contains the full path, or, when your file is in your Present Working Directory, use [`pwd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pwd.html)

```matlab
my_folder = '/path/to/folder/';
files = dir(my_folder)  % Grab all files
fullpath = [files(ii).folder files(ii).name];  % Generate full path

% Or, if the file is in the PWD
files = dir(my_folder)  % Grab all files
fullpath = [pwd files(ii).name];  % Generate full path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all files with the command dir, the following code will display the names of all files:

```
files = dir;
files.name
```

Then, you have to get the file you want.